# performance of fread/fwrite while doing operation with binary file

Tags: c++, c

I am writing some binary data into a binary file through fwrite and once i am through with writing i am reading back the same data thorugh fread.While doing this i found that fwrite is taking less time to write whole data where as fread is taking more time to read all data.
So, i just want to know is it fwrite always takes less time than fread or there is some issue with my reading portion.

Comment: why did this get downvoted? seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 4):

Although, as others have said, there are no guarantees, you'll typically find that a single write will be faster than a single read. The write will be likely to copy the data into a buffer and return straight away, while the read will be likely to wait for the data to be fetched from the storage device. Sometimes the write will be slow if the buffers fill up; sometimes the read will be fast if the data has already been fetched. And sometimes one of the many layers of abstraction between `fread`/`fwrite` and the storage hardware will decide to go off into its own little world for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ language makes no guarantees on the comparative performance of these (or any other) functions. It is all down to the combination of hardware and operating system, the load on the machine and the phase of the moon.

Comment: Agreed. There's a whole set of layers between you and the hardware and often buffering of data in memory so impossible to generalise on this

Comment: Totally correct. But does not provide any reasonable explanation of why (or potentially why). If we expect others to improve you at least need to mention the parts that could slow the process down so they can do more research (like the OS IO caching mechanism mention by the other three answers).

Comment: @Martin As usual, we are not in agreement n how to answer SO questions. But you do it your way, and I'll continue to do it mine.

Answer (score 2):

These functions interact with the operating system's file system cache.  In many cases it is a simple memory-to-memory copy.  Write could indeed be marginally faster if you run your program repeatedly.  It just needs to find a hole in the cache to dump its data.  Flushing that data to the disk happens at a time you can't see or measure.

More work is usually needed to read.  At a minimum it needs to traverse the cache structure to discover if the disk data is already cached.  If not, it is going to have to block on a disk driver request to retrieve the data from the disk, that takes many milliseconds.

The standard trap with profiling this behavior is taking measurements from repeated runs of your program.  They are not at all representative for the way your program is going to behave in the wild.  The odds that the disk data is already cached are *very* good on the second run of your program.  They are very poor in real life, reads are likely to be very slow, especially the first one.  An extra special trap exists for a write, at some point (depending on the behavior of other programs too), the cache is not going to be able to buffer the write request.  Write performance is then going to fall of a cliff as your program gets blocked until enough data is flushed to the disk.

Long story short: don't *ever* assume disk read/write performance measurements are representative for how your program will behave in production.  And perhaps more to the point: there isn't anything you can do to solve disk I/O perf problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing some effect of the buffer/cache systems as other have said, however, if you use async API (as you said your suing fread/write you should look at aio_read/aio_write) you can experiment with some other methods for I/O which are likely more well optimized for what your doing.

One suggestion is that if you are read/update/write/reading a file a lot, you should, by way of an ioctl or DeviceIOControl, request to the OS to provide you the geometry of the disk your code is running on, then determine the size of a disk cylander so you may be able to determine if you can do your read/write operations buffered inside of a single cylinder.  This way, the drive head will not move for your read/write and save you a fair amount of run time.